# Erro ao agupar subquery do MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Possuo um select para exibir 4 campos, porém um campo que é o `valor_pago` é de outra tabela, mas não posso utilizar `JOIN` senão o retorno dos registros conflita

Então criei uma `Subquery` mas minha dúvida é: como faço para que o meu montante de `SUM(valor_pago)` seja agrupado por mês. Tentei alterar minha `subquery` de duas formas, sem sucesso:

`SELECT MONTH(data_pagamento, SUM(valor_pago)`

> Operand should countaim 1 columns

E tentei agrupar com `GROUP BY MONTH(data_pagamento)`]

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

O erro é que, ele faz a soma anual e printa em todos os campos com este código que estou utilizando

```
    SELECT 
        MONTH(P.data_venda), 
        SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) AS Faturamento, 
        SUM(P.custo_total) AS Custos, 
        SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) - SUM(P.custo_total) AS Lucro, 
       (SELECT 
            SUM(valor_pago) 
        FROM contapag
        WHERE empresa = 1 
        AND filial = 1 
        AND data_pagamento BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' 
        AND valor_pago > 0) AS Despesas 
    FROM pedido P
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Min(pedido) as formapag_rec,empresa, filial, pedido, plano as formapag_plano FROM formapag
       WHERE empresa = 1  AND filial = 1
       GROUP BY empresa, filial, pedido) F ON F.empresa = P.empresa and F.filial = P.filial and F.pedido = P.pedido
   LEFT JOIN plano on plano.plano = formapag_plano
       WHERE P.empresa = 1 AND P.filial = 1 AND data_venda BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' AND P.vlr_tot_liquido > 0 AND P.status = 'FIN' AND (plano.especie <> 'MOV' OR plano.especie is null)
       GROUP BY YEAR(P.data_venda), MONTH(P.data_venda)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tente utilizar o SQLFiddle e replicar seu ambiente para testes: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só filtrar a subquery pelo mês da query principal:

```
        SELECT 
            MONTH(P.data_venda), 
            SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) AS Faturamento, 
            SUM(P.custo_total) AS Custos, 
            SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) - SUM(P.custo_total) AS Lucro, 
           (SELECT 
                SUM(valor_pago) 
            FROM contapag
            WHERE empresa = 1 
            AND filial = 1 
            AND data_pagamento BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' 
            AND valor_pago > 0 
            AND MONTH(data_pagamento) = MONTH(P.data_venda)
            AND YEAR(data_pagamento) = YEAR(P.data_venda)) AS Despesas 
        FROM pedido P
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Min(pedido) as formapag_rec,empresa, filial, pedido, plano as formapag_plano FROM formapag
           WHERE empresa = 1  AND filial = 1
           GROUP BY empresa, filial, pedido) F ON F.empresa = P.empresa and F.filial = P.filial and F.pedido = P.pedido
       LEFT JOIN plano on plano.plano = formapag_plano
           WHERE P.empresa = 1 AND P.filial = 1 AND data_venda BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' AND P.vlr_tot_liquido > 0 AND P.status = 'FIN' AND (plano.especie <> 'MOV' OR plano.especie is null)
           GROUP BY YEAR(P.data_venda), MONTH(P.data_venda)
```

Comment: eu até tentei desta forma @RovannLinhalis porém ele acusa erro no momento do WHERE MONT(data_pagamento) = MONTH(P.data_venda) e não sei porque , no seu código deu a mesma coisa. Muito estranho né

Comment: qual erro? pra ser sincero, não verifiquei o resto da query

Comment: consegui cara, obrigado por compartilhar da sua inteligência, só tem um erro no seu código ai,  deveria ficar AND valor_pago > 0 AND MONTH(...) vou editar

Comment: uma besteirinha... passou batido.. blz, vlww

Comment: eu que agradeço cara muito obrigado